# Plutus-pioneer-progra cabal build error

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

when I built plutus-pioneer-program lecture week2, I got the error like this

```
/root/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-crypto-praos-2.1.0.0-6256b7c51bff5ecd7a4cd62d0cae080568903ed67a7b8424037c5be2d1c7a1d9/lib/libHScardano-crypto-praos-2.1.0.0-6256b7c51bff5ecd7a4cd62d0cae080568903ed67a7b8424037c5be2d1c7a1d9.a(Praos.o):ghc_18.c:function cardanozmcryptozmpraoszm2zi1zi0zi0zm6256b7c51bff5ecd7a4cd62d0cae080568903ed67a7b8424037c5be2d1c7a1d9_CardanoziCryptoziVRFziPraos_zdwzdcevalVRF_info:(.text+0xa354): error: undefined reference to 'crypto_vrf_ietfdraft03_proof_to_hash'
```

it seems link cardano-crypto-praos error, how to solve it?

Comment: Which set of instructions are you using to build this? My suspicion is that you have either skipped a step or the instructions are incomplete.

Comment: I think I didn't skipped some step, I just installed all deps manually, and run 'cabal build'. When I tried to build cardano-node, it is also failed, the same command 'cabal build'

Comment: Following the links from the README file in the `cardano-node` repo leads to this  https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node-wiki/blob/main/docs/getting-started/install.md .I think you missed the "installing libsodium" section and maybe more.